# Page renders properly only if showHeader="false"

Tags: visualforce, google-map

I have a page that will render properly only when showHeader="false" in the apex:page tag.

When it's set to true I get the following...

[image]

However, when it's set to false, I get a full-page map from Google (further down).

My page is very simple...

```
<apex:page standardController="Feral_Cat_Map__c"  showHeader="false" >
    <c:mapping /> 
</apex:page>
```

Then the component is...

```
<apex:component controller="mappingController">
    <!-- A lot of JavaScript -->

    <body class="area">
        <div id="panel">
            <b>Enter address: </b><input id="address" type="textbox" size="50" />
            <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="geocodeAddress()"/>
            </div><br/><br/><br/>
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>             
    </body>
</apex:component>
```

So - have you come across this before?  Any ideas why changing the showHeader setting would cause it to fail?

What it should look like follows...with the header added, of course

[image]

Comment: Some of your javascript code clashes with the standard salesforce javascript. Try rename some of your global variables and methods see if that fixes it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure having a `<body>` tag in a component might be the cause of your pain...

Comment: @LaceySnr - thanks for the tip but the behavior is exactly the same with the body tag in the component or in the page.

Comment: Doh, worth a crack. What's controlling the styling for the map?

Comment: Styling is from Google Maps settings (mostly defaults) with custom based on logic in the JS code.  Data's coming in via JS remoting to the Apex controller.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Try adding this to the page applyBodyTag="false"

Comment: @PepeFloyd thanks for the suggestion, sadly it didn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

Since the solution isn't obvious, I was thinking...it works perfect when added as a VisualForce page through the Layout Editor (shown below).

So, rather than hunting for the problem, couldn't I just mimic that infrastructure?

What does the wrapper around dropped in pages look like?

[image]

Comment: sberley, did you want to make an edit to your question ? It's a "best practise" to keep all parts of your question centralized there, so that answers are **only** solutions to that questoin and not replies. If you're new to stackexchange, i'd recommend having a look at our [welcome your](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

I had posted this on another thread asking about a different approach that might solve the problem.  Shortly afterward I had an idea that resolve it.

See this posting in case you're faced with a similar problem...

- [Simulating containers from VF layout editor on page w/o sObject](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/74060/simulating-containers-from-vf-layout-editor-on-page-w-o-sobject/74061#74061)

Good luck,

Steve