# Simulating containers from VF layout editor on page w/o sObject

Tags: visualforce, google-map

*(n.b. While the underlying problem described here was originally asked days ago, this posting asks for assistance from a totally different perspective)*

I have a VF page containing a map that works when I add to standard pages through the Layout Editor

[image]

If I put it in its own page, with headers off it also works fine, but if headers are on it fails.

Since it's working perfectly when added through the layout editor, how do I accomplish either of the following...

1. Use the VF page editor on a new blank page that isn't tied to an sObject controller?

...or...

2. Replicate the container structure used by those pages and displays my map element?  I'm pretty sure it's an iFrame, but I have no idea how to refer to my

Thanks for the help with this stumper...

Answer (score 2):

Since this was a vexing problem to which I found a solution, I'm posting the trick I used in case others face something similar in the future...

The page that includes the map is called `MapPage` and contains the following:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" >
   <c:mapping/> 
</apex:page>
```

I created a second page that's a wrapper called `DisplayMap` with contents of...

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" >
   <apex:iframe src="/apex/MapPage"/> 
</apex:page>
```

When I go to `[Salesforce URL]/apex/DisplayMap` it works perfectly!

If this helps you please give me an up arrow for the cred points.

Thanks

Comment: did u try using apex:include instead of iframe to embed the mappage inside displaymap ? https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_include.htm

Comment: If you want cred points, it's better to ask for them in a comment, this way it's a little separated from the answer.